# iTextSharp - PDF Fonts TT1B4t00 Wrong Size

Tags: pdf, itext

I'm iTextSharp to get text Chunks to build words and get locations from existing PDFs.  I'm using the font size to calculate the inline chunks and size of the "word".  This has been working perfectly, but recently I have come across existing PDFs created by a writer (ClarityPDF) which makes the font TT1B4t00.  When I read the chunks using iTextSharp I get a different size, which gives me an incorrect location.

All the PDF documents use Arial Narrow 12pt.  I have made a simple test using the ClarityPDF and BluebeamPDF writers on the same document.

The results:

- Both writers put the document origin in the same location.
- Both writers keep the location points and size of the document the same.
- The fonts are different and when printed out to console I get different sizes.  The Arial is 12pt and TT1B4t00 is about 5pt.

Image of document created with BluebeamPDF
[image]

Image of document created with ClarityPDF
[image]

- Is there a way to convert these back to Arial Narrow 12 pt programmatically?
- Has anyone seen font style TT1B4t00? If so might it have a scale factor or unit type which I'm missing and can add to my program?
- Could the problem be something which I haven't thought of?

files 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uq9rWz10u31Fhkp39UtkYc-W1GZPooih/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E0LPXRGWATBW1nrlDKk4Oo4BvMBnxBIC/view?usp=sharing

Here is my sample code of Render text method which gets the text location and font size.

```
// **************************RenderText**************************
    public void RenderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo)
    {
        // Get the current line 
        LineSegment segment = renderInfo.GetBaseline();
        var location = new TextChunk(renderInfo.GetText(), segment.GetStartPoint(), segment.GetEndPoint(), renderInfo.GetSingleSpaceWidth());

        Debug.Print(renderInfo.GetText());
        // Get position and location of text. 
        Vector horizonCoordinate = renderInfo.GetDescentLine().GetStartPoint();
        Vector verticalRight = renderInfo.GetAscentLine().GetEndPoint();
        location.PosLeft = horizonCoordinate[Vector.I1];
        location.PosRight = verticalRight[Vector.I1];
        location.PosBottom = horizonCoordinate[Vector.I2];
        location.PosTop = verticalRight[Vector.I2];

        location.curFontSize = location.PosTop - segment.GetStartPoint()[Vector.I2];

        string strKey = string.Concat(renderInfo.GetFont().PostscriptFontName, location.curFontSize);
        // Add fonts types to a list. 
        if (!ThisPdfDocFonts.ContainsKey(strKey))
        {
            ThisPdfDocFonts.Add(strKey, renderInfo.GetFont());

            Console.WriteLine(strKey);
            Console.WriteLine(location.curFontSize);
        }


        // Set font type to chunk
        location.FontIndex = ThisPdfDocFonts.IndexOfKey(strKey);
        // add chunk to list 
        string txt = location.text;
        locationalResult.Add(location);
    }
```

Would the media size and rotation affect the renderInfo?  I notieced the renderInfo isn't the same when looking at the two PDFs.  I inspected the PDFs and noticed that the Media isn't consistant. 
[image]

Many thanks.

Comment: Please share a sample pdf and your pivotal code.

Comment: "Has anyone seen font style TT1B4t00?" That is a random name, generated for the subset of the full font. Even if anyone got that exact *name* earlier (quite big chance there, because it's just a handful of characters out of a very limited set), the chance that it contains *the exact subset of the exact same font* is exactly 0.0%.

Comment: You determine the font size as the vertical distance between ascent line and base line. That completely ignores the font descent. And in particular for font subsets the ascent value might be much lower than the top of some glyphs in the full font.

Comment: This might be right about getting the height using AcentPoint - DecentPoint, however  I think the renderinfo is giving me different values.  I tried to print a word document using both writers and just the text ABC and I noticed that the TextRenderInfo renderinfo is different location.  I noticed this also on other test prints.

Current Font Size: 10.92035, 
Pos Left: 71.99997, 
Pos Right: 74.49023, 
Pos Bottom: 709.5601, 
Pos Top: 720.6

Current Font Size: 10.62878, 
Pos Left: 70.07947, 
Pos Right: 72.50788, 
Pos Bottom: 725.9642, 
Pos Top: 736.7095

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PDF writer is rotating the PDF 90 degrees which I was able to see using itext-rups-5.5.9.  This is odd because you can't see this rotation in the viewer.  Also, the ClarityPDF writer is mirroring the coordinate system in the Y-Axis in the middle of the drawing. Once I accounted for those two things the chunk locations are correct.